# How to wrap all words in a document with vim?

Tags: python, vim

[Here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.names) is the file and on line 97 and below are the lines that I want to put in a python dictionary, idea is that words on left side of colon ':' will become keys and on right side of it will be values. All keys and values must be strings and for that I need to wrap all words (from line 97 and below) in quotation. So the question is **How to wrap all words, in a document, in quotes?**

My purpose of doing this is to obtain column names for prepossessing for machine learning. If you are interested you can find columns without names [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data).

Comment: Put the relevant parts of the text you want to work with *in* your question, each line indented by four spaces.

Comment: Posting a file called adult.names isn't going to get me to open it ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to know exactly what you mean if you don't post the code (and no, I am not going to download and open a file called adult.names from a random person on the internet). However, if all you want is for every word to be wrapped in quotes, you can use a global substitution:

```
:%s/\w\+\ze[\s, \n, :]\+/"\0"/g
```

#### Explanation:

- `:s/regex/text` will replace whatever is matched by `regex` with `text` on the current line.
- Add a `%` at the beginning and it will do it for all lines.

  - If you only want to do this for a section of your document, make a visual selection and then run this command without the `%`.
- `\w` matches a word character
- `\ze` ends the match (so you can specify what comes after whatever you're matching)
- The `[\s, \n, :]` means match spaces, newlines, and colons, and the `\+` following that means match a non-zero number of those (i.e. at least one whitespace character or newline or colon).

All of that together means it's matching each word individually.

- Then, for each of those matched words, it is replacing it with a quotation mark, then `\0` which means the first thing that was substituted before, and another quotation mark.
- The `/g` at the end means that it will do this substitution as many times as it finds the regex on each line. Without that it would only substitute the first match on each line.

The result should be that it wraps every word in quotes. But again, it's difficult to test and find the right solution without seeing what you're working with. In the future please put the relevant pieces of code in your post.

Comment: Thank you it works, I just did not now what to answer so could not reply. I use vim because it saves time not because I am expert.
I still do not understand what code you want? If you like python file (code) I can upload it and link in next comment.

Comment: If what I gave you works, then it's fine for now, but in the future copying and pasting the relevant code (in this case, probably the part where you initialize your dictionary) into your post is preferable to putting a link to it. If you begin each line with 4 spaces, it will get formatted as a code block. Its okay for this question if my solution worked though.

Comment: Your solution works, and thank you for explanation that was helpful. I understand now what you mean by "code" you wanted to see how I implement, I did not consider it relevant since I thought this community would not know python syntax. Thanks anyway.